# ¿Por qué se duplican los elementos en un asp:DropDownList solo cuando aplico un selectpicker?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc, vb.net

Estoy enfrentando un problema al asignar la clase CSS 'selectpicker' a mi asp:DropDownList. Necesito utilizar selectpicker para habilitar la funcionalidad de búsqueda dentro del DropDownList. Sin embargo, al aplicar esta clase, el elemento se duplica dos veces en la pantalla. Si elimino 'selectpicker' y solo dejo 'form-control', no hay duplicación, pero pierdo la capacidad de búsqueda que necesito. He revisado el evento Page_Load y las etiquetas UpdatePanels, y parecen estar configurados correctamente. A pesar de estos controles, el problema persiste. ¿Alguien podría orientarme sobre qué más podría revisar o volver a verificar para solucionar este inconveniente y aún así mantener la funcionalidad de búsqueda proporcionada por selectpicker?

[image: Imagen del problema del DDL]

```
  <div class="col-md-4"  style="padding-top: 10px;">
  <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlProyecto"  CssClass="form-control selectpicker" data-show-subtext="true" data-live-search="true" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlProyecto_SelectedIndexChanged"></asp:DropDownList>
```